# What is the syntax of `Some()`?

Tags: rust, enums, syntax

In `Rust`, `Option` enum is declared as:

```
pub enum Option<T> {
    /// No value
    #[lang = "None"]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    None,
    /// Some value `T`
    #[lang = "Some"]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    Some(#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")] T),
}
```

And we know an `Option` value can be created via:

```
Some("Apple")
```

---

### Questions

1. What is this syntax for `Some(T)` and `Some("Apple")`?
   It looks like a function, but didn't find relevant source code for it.
2. When I try to create a similar enum, as:

   ```rust
   pub enum Food<T> {
       Fruit(T),
   }

   impl<T> Food<T> {
       pub const fn unwrap(self) -> T {
           match self {
               Self::Fruit(val) => val,
           }
       }
   }

   fn x() {
       let a = Food::Fruit("apple");
       println!("{}", a.unwrap());
   }
   ```

   and get error:

   ```
    error[E0493]: destructors cannot be evaluated at compile-time
      --> src/lib.rs:6:25
       |
    6  |     pub const fn unwrap(self) -> T {
       |                         ^^^^ constant functions cannot evaluate destructors
    ...
    10 |     }
       |     - value is dropped here
   ```

   Is it possible to create such an enum? If so, how to fix the issues?

Comment: It works if you remove `const`?

Comment: You should make your questions into two separate posts. They aren't really related to each other.

Comment: @kmdreko The 2nd question is just trying to figure what the 1st question ask about, if the 1st question can be answered, then the 2nd one could be ignored.

Comment: @Herohtar Yes, removing `const` on `unwrap()` does work.

Comment: what you used is [EnumTuple](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/enumerations.html?highlight=enum%20constru#enumerations) that imply a tuple constructor https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/tuple-expr.html#tuple-expressions

Comment: @Stargateur Ok, the `Dog(String, f64),` example from https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/enumerations.html#enumerations makes it more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define an enum with the various variant types:

```
pub enum Food {
    Onion,
    Fruit(String),
    Pizza { toppings: Vec<Food> },
}
```

The syntax to create an instance of that enum via the variant types are as follows:

```
let o: Food = Food::Onion;
let f: Food = Food::Fruit("Mango".to_string());
let p: Food = Food::Pizza { toppings: vec![] };
```

The tuple variants can stand on their own (without `Food::`) if they are exported as such:

```
use Food::*; // brings Onion, Fruit, and Pizza into scope

let o: Food = Onion;
let f: Food = Fruit("Mango".to_string());
let p: Food = Pizza { toppings: vec![] };
```

The `Option::None` and `Option::Some` use this globally for convenience.

> It looks like a function, but didn't find relevant source code for it.

Properly each use is an *enum constructor* it has no source other than its definition, but you actually *can* use `Fruit` as a function:

```
fn convert<T, U, F: Fn(T) -> U>(f: F, t: T) -> U {
    f(t)
}

fn main() {
    let f: Food = convert(Food::Fruit, "mango".to_string());
}
```

---

You get an error when defining `pub const fn unwrap(self) -> T` because `const` functions are still in development and not all future usage is stabilized yet. This works for `Option::unwrap` because, as part of the standard library, it's getting special treatment.

You can read more about other `const` functions for `Option` here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67441. Or see information on the development of `const fn`s in general here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57563

Comment: So, regarding the 1st question: simply put, in fields, `()` is tuple, `{}` is struct; thus `Some(T)` is just a tuple with a single item of type `T`.

Comment: `Some` is a "tuple variant", `None` is a "unit variant", and `Pizza {}` is a "struct variant". The similarities are definitely there, but be careful; `Some(T)` is *not* a tuple, a tuple has type `(T)` whereas `Some(T)` has type `Option<T>`. Hope that clears things up.